# Best practice for searching more than one entity

Tags: ios, objective-c, nsfetchedresultscontroller

I would like to implement a search function for my app that searches multiple entities, i.e. meat, fish, cheese, staples.  This seems pretty desirable functionality but from what I've read there is no ideal way to do it.  You either assemble an array manually or if you use NSFetched results controller, you have to do something complicated to map index paths.

The alternative would be to have a separate search for each tableviewcontroller but that seems clunky.

Has anyone devised a reliable way to do this?  In 2016, what is best practice for searching multiple entities?  Thanks in advance for any suggestions.

Comment: a parent entity `Food`?

Answer (score 0):

You can define a search-dedicated entity SearchItem, which links to the source meats, fishes, cheeses, etc.

You then have a single NSFetchedResultsController that searches in SearchItems. Make sure you use `-[NSFetchRequest setRelationshipKeyPathsForPrefetching:]` method so that the linked objects are prefetched and your table view loads faster.